# Calling copy and assignment operators from base class to create inherited class instances in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, c++98

I have te following classes (e.g.) :

```
class A {

   public:
   A(void) : i(0) {}
   A(int val) : i(val) {} 
   A(const A& other) : i(other.i) {}
   A& operator=(const A& other) {
       i = other.i;
       return *this;
   }

   int i;
};

class B : public A {

   public:
   B(void) : A(), j(0) {};
   B(const B& other) : A(other), j(other.j) {}
   B(int i, int j) : A(other.i), j(other.j) {}
   B& operator=(const B& other) {
      A::operator=(other);
      j = other.j;
      return *this;
   }
   
   int j;
};
```

My question is, given the `operator=` overload and copy constructor in `B`, if I wanted to be able to create instances of `B` out of an already initialized instance of `A`, or to assign existing instances of `A` to existing instances of `B`, would it be necessary to define another copy constructor on `B` and `operator=` with the following signature ?:

```
B(const A& other);
B& operator=(const A& other);
```

The goal would be to be able to instantiate/assign derived class instances only with the Base class information.
PS : I am working in C++98 and unable to use any newer standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to define something like that.

B(const A& other);

This would allow constructing `B` out of `A`. This would also allow assigning `A` to `B` by way of implicitly converting `A` to `B` and then assigning. So that alone should suffice. But you get an extra copy.

```
B& operator=(const A& other);
```

This makes assigning `A` to `B` more efficient since you avoid the extra copy of the temporary `B`. This should also allow assigning things that can be implicitly converted to `A` like:

```
B b = 1;
```

If you don't want that you might have to add some `explicit`. Did C++98 have explicit? That is so last millenium.

Note: In modern C++ this would be more efficient because of copy elision and because you could use move semantic and perfect forwarding references.

Comment: C++98 allows only constructors to be `explicit`. I did implement (before this answer though, just trying things out) the extra copy constructor and assignment operator and it worked as intended. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal would be to be able to instantiate/assign derived class instances only with the Base class information.

Your goal sounds fishy to me.

Normally in practice, you have two distinct scenarios:

- data objects (requiring no inheritance hierarchy)
- behavior objects (implementing the same interface, through inheritance).

Data objects (since they have no common base class) implement instantiation and assignment (copy constructors and assignment operators).

Behavior objects (objects within class hierarchies) cannot implement assignment from base class objects in a generic way (what will you do with member variables that exist in the derived class but not in the base class? give them a default value? leave them unchanged?).

That said, you should use a different API than copy constructor and assignment in order to avoid confusion and implicit casts.

That is, if you have both:

```
B& operator=(const B&);
B& operator=(const A&);
```

then this is ambiguous when the code assigns from a B instance (as the compiler could call either of them).

You could add a `B::copy_common_values(const A&);`. This would make it more explicit as well.

In case you are trying to solve an x-y problem, also look up prototype design pattern.

Comment: Objects A and B in my code are both data objects. B is just a data extension of A. Because having just one class A with also all of what would be B information seemed not optimal, since A instances would often not need B fields. 
My code, then, creates B instances from A, as it expands the information in A. But omitting then standard B copy constructors to just have `B(const &A other)` did not seem like a solution.

Comment: Also, why is it ambiguous if I am using references ? If a `B` instance is declared and then assigned to some other `B` instance, why would the compiler think the right hand side is an `A` instance, if it was clearly initialized as a `B` one and there is an explicit operator for that case ?

Comment: `Objects A and B in my code are both data objects. B is just a data extension of A`. 
Consider making an instance of A, a member of B and avoiding inheritance in this case? (just an idea - I don't know if it applies to your problem).

Comment: I thought about that but I wanted to first explore other possibilities.I might end up doing that since it seems like a more straightforward solution. Thank you for your help.